# How to keep old local setting data while upgrading windows application?

Tags: c#

This question is continue with [How to keep Settings details in Visual Studio application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136808/how-to-keep-settings-details-in-visual-studio-application/37137236?noredirect=1#comment61817032_37137236)  ticket.

I have tried by following but it set blank my old LocalSetting data.
Program.cs

```
//get current version which is 1.1.0 after upgrade
string tempVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
tempVersion = tempVersion.Remove(tempVersion.Length - 2);
//tempVersion = 1.1.0

//it will check whether is new version installed
//Settings.Default.ProductCurrentVersion = 1.0.0. So, it will called
if (Settings.Default.ProductCurrentVersion != tempVersion)
{
    MessageBox.Show("New Version: " +tempVersion);
    MessageBox.Show("Old Version: " +Settings.Default.ProductCurrentVersion);
    Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Settings.Default.Save();
    //Local Settings data will be blank here.
}
```

Can anybody suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: @timothyclifford I have tried this as all they suggest by `Settings.Default.Upgrade();` but it blank my string type values. Also review this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136808/how-to-keep-settings-details-in-visual-studio-application/37137236#37137236

Comment: Please followup with your original question until you've marked it as answered.

Comment: Have you check that `Settings.Default` contains data before calling `Upgrade()`?

Comment: @timothyclifford It's done. I misunderstood the approach has been suggested.